# Redirect http traffic to https on a non standard apache port

Tags: https, apache2

I have a website running at https://example.com:555

The 80 and 443 port for the same public ip have been forwarded to another server.

I only want to re-direct the url from http://example.com:555/1618/?id=877 to https://example.com:555/1618/?id=877

Right now I am getting the 400 error "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand..."

I am using apache 2.4 on ubuntu 20.04

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

1. adding "ErrorDocument 400 [https://example.com:555"](https://example.com:555%22) in .htaccess
   works but the id parameter is not passed
2. adding ErrorDocument in the localized-error-pages.conf in apache
   works but the id parameter is not passed
3. configure Strict-Transport-Security
   didnt work
4. trying different $1 , REQUEST_URI etc in .htaccess
   did not work

Comment: From `http://example.com:555` to `https://example.com:555`? So your web server is able to serve both HTTP _and_ HTTPS requests under the same port? How did you manage to achieve that in the first place ...?

Comment: In this case, you can't make the decision dependent on the port, and the `https://` part of the requested URL your server doesn't actually get to "see" anywhere. So I suppose you can only check what the `HTTPS` environment variable contains, and hope the server populates that correctly under these circumstances.

Comment: `Right now I am getting the 400 error`...in response to which request, precisely?

Comment: :CBroe Server accepts only https , not http, if http request is received it throws a 400 error
:ADyson the standard 400 error, when http is requested at https port

What I am trying to accomplish is basically redirect http traffic requested at https port to https 
Hope it helps.

Comment: That's not what a redirect is. A redirect is the webserver receiving a (valid) request to a URL, but then telling the browser to go to another URL instead. But for that to work, the first URL has to be actually real and usable, so the webserver can process it, examine it, and then decide to issue the redirect header. Since you cannot listen for both HTTP and HTTPS connections on the same port, what you're asking for is essentially impossible. If you had a different port listening for HTTP requests, you could easily redirect requests to that port over to the HTTPS port.

Comment: But in the scenario you're describing, it's down to the client making the request to correctly specify the protocol to use for accessing that port. Otherwise, the webserver will simply not understand it, hence the error.

Comment: Have you read this https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html?